# Read .pbix file content through C# or java

Tags: datasource, powerbi

I am when trying to use java / c# or any other programming language to modify .pbix file which generated from Microsoft Power BI. Is there any dll provided by POWER BI or how can i read the content through program. I just want to get and update the datasource directory. Please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible, and even if it is, the solution is likely inelegant.

Even if you managed to do this, you would need to open your PBIX file in the PBI Desktop to refresh your data.

Are you doing this because you have many queries and it's inconvenient to change data source string (folder name) of all of them? There is a way to keep your connection string in a single variable as described [here](https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2015/11/09/avoiding-duplication-of-database-connection-information-in-power-bi/).

---

I don't know your exact setup, but looking at your question, lets say you have sets of files in different folders and you want to change the folder in one step.

To use the approach from the link above but with file input, you need to do the following:

- If it's a new report, import your files as usual
- Create new query: "New Source"->"Blank Query"
- You will see "Query1" and an empty text box, enter the folder name, for example "C:\". Rename this query to "Folder".
  [image]
- Go to your imported file in the query editor, "test1" in my example. In query settings on the right, select source.
- Change the filename by substituting the folder with your "Folder" query, for example:
  `...File.Contents("C:\test1.csv"),...`
  `...File.Contents(Folder & "test1.csv"),...`
  [image]
- Repeat for all imported files, then "Close & Apply".
- Now whenever you need to change the folder with your files, edit your "Folder" value and "Refresh".

Comment: I'd like to point out that just because you think a solution is "inelegant" doesn't mean it isn't worth exploring. I hope nobody reads your post and allows you to discourage them from trying this. There very much is a business case for wanting to do this.

Comment: @Brad someone can probably "hack" their way through to achieve this, and it may even work until the next PowerBI update. But this is not very sustainable in production / real world, especially if you are paying for this product. MS need to release an officially supported way to do this.

Comment: I can definitely agree with that. Terms like inelegant are thrown around too much to justify wanting or not wanting to do something, in my opinion. Thanks for further explaining.